# Retonar a tela do App - Android Cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova

estou desenvolvendo um app para Android usando Cordova, na minha tela de login, eu mando os dados para um arquivo no meu domínio, ele faz a requisição pega os dados, agora, como voltar a tela do app para confirmação dos dados, ou seja, ele vai fazer a requisicao em um arquivo que ta no ar, e voltar pro app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode solucionar este problema de varias formas.

O primeiro passo é entender o que você realmente precisa, caso você precise somente os dados para validar o login do usuário você pode utilizar `JSONP`, fazendo uma requisição simples com os dados do formulário. Utilize JavaScript para conseguir os valores dos `Inputs`. Você também pode utilizar um retorno simples em HTML. Para acessar estes dados você pode utilizar `jQuery`. Utilizando jQuery você pode utilizar o get passando usuário e  a senha.

```
$.get( "dominio.com.br/login.php?usuario=" + usuario + "&senha=" + senha, function(dados) {
  // Executa algum código com o resultado
});
```

Com isso é possível efetuar login e conseguir as informações de forma simples. Também é possível utilizar `POST`.

É preciso deixar claro que ao se utilizar `JSON` ou mesmo com `JSONP` ao efetuar requisições de dados  por meio do JavaScript você pode encontrar erros em relação ao CrossDomain, como sua aplicação não possui o mesmo domínio do conteúdo que esta sendo acessado, o WebKit tenta bloquear este acesso. Procure sobre `Cross Domain`, `JSONP` e `CORS` para entendimento melhor sobre o assunto.

Caso você precise realmente abrir o navegador do SmarthPhone para efetuar algum tipo de autenticação como da conta do `Twitter` ou `Google` você pode criar uma janela e armazenar ela em uma variável, o JavaScript só pode fechar janelas que ele tenha aberto. Desta forma basta você abrir a janela, armazenar em uma variável e quando a autenticação estiver ok você simplesmente fecha a janela.

O exemplo abaixo deixa isso bem claro, é aberto uma janela e armazenado em uma variável, então é criado um Listener para o evento `loadstop`, este Listener define que após 5 segundos a janela deve ser fechada.
No seu caso verifique se o sistema de autenticação oferece suporte a uma função de callback ou se emite algum evento quando autenticado, neste caso não é preciso fechar após receber o evento de carregamento completo, você pode fechar apenas quando receber o evento correto.

```
   var win = window.open( "http://docs.kendoui.com", "_blank", "EnableViewPortScale=yes" );
    win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            win.close();
        }, 5000 );
    });
```

**Links que podem ajudar:**

[Cross Window Communication With Cordova's InAppBrowser](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser)

[So, JSONP or CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296910/so-jsonp-or-cors)

[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

[Jquery Cross Domain Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989505/jquery-cross-domain-ajax)